# Type is not comparable to type in generic abstract class

Tags: typescript

I implemented builder pattern for complex data structure, in which some values and created via builders:

```js
export interface Builder<Product> {
  build(): Product;
}

export type Element<T> = T extends Array<infer Y> ? Y : T;
export type BuilderInit<Product, Key extends keyof Product> = (
  product: Product,
) => Builder<Element<Product[Key]>>;

abstract class ParentBuilder<Product extends object> {
  readonly #childrenMap = new Map<
    keyof Product,
    BuilderInit<Product, keyof Product>[]
  >();

  protected setChild<Key extends keyof Product>(
    key: Key,
    cb: BuilderInit<Product, Key>,
  ) {
    this.#childrenMap.set(key, [cb]);

    return this;
  }
}
```

`ParentBuilder` is a base class that all other builders will extend, which allows to add child builders for some property of the `ParentBuilder`'s product.

For instance considering product:

```js
interface CompanyAssets {
  trucks: Truck[];
}
```

There might be builder for `Truck`:

```
class Truck {
  color!: string;
}

class TruckBuilder implements Builder<Truck> {
  build() {
    return new Truck();
  }
}
```

Next, I create yet another abstract class that extends `ParentBuilder`. That class is supposed to enhance `ParentClass` with some additional methods.

```
abstract class CompanyAssetsBuilder<Product extends CompanyAssets> extends ParentBuilder<Product> {
  setTruck() {
    return this.setChild("trucks", () => {
      return new TruckBuilder() as Builder<Element<Product["trucks"]>>;
    });
  }
}
```

Thus far everything is working as expected, but the issue starts when I try to add methods or properties to the `TrackBuilder`. Then typescript thinks that `TruckBuilder` is not comparable to the `Builder<Element<Product["trucks"]>>` which I find odd since concrete implementation should be assignable to return value of the callback.

For now I cast return value to `unknown` as suggested by compiler error message, but I would like to know why this is happening in the first place.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgIQFcEAbAEzQB4AFKCMw7GAPjgG8BYAKDjgCNi5ABQBKAFxxa9RjADc3AL7duoSLDgwAnmDwBREsAC2wFJQAqrALxwzcUKiRkAznACCUKJk2Vk6NHABNVgB+QLgJM3kuVWh4LR0CQQooAEkkBBgaOgYmABo4AGlgTTsQB2c4AGtiiHRJbJkrOCFuXjAGpgkpHJhc7hE4S1YiUmTKfSMTTO6ZAG0izQBdZmYo7kw+JxhPJjhsEkwnF2pMKCmR8ioZ3fsTCog+ACtgJlZOHjgzzDIIJBISgDE2AAFqMzkgALKYMCDOBIYAAdzgULAlFavCqNTq1166N4F2SaQyWWkeUxmlq9VJLFmi3RzFEaw+7QgqCYwDIcCcwBgAGFQeRKAtSuUXNUKdiOiwWh9eOKJAs+rK9nwJAS0ETplL8gtmEreAN3hiNKCnAA6IECsjglFm7kwITi-KzbB8RYiJnGs4wQhQJAmhBOKK8JRcUPcZCoDA4PC8iCGMCYJCaVxHHkuI0aKCMSpOCLZ7CVWlRcNcfaHFxmAuVdjo7AQEjQACEEi2UGQAHMS8oywcjjZq+qoIgEwZjCgXEPzNW3uiAPRztzJuDfMgZBC-TAkPb0PC-AMucv9wN7TCEJydk14QNOQh4PjARsIs3opzx4AQnnA+iiWvKhd2AmWjoqGvDogIoy-pmvDer6-rwkiVY5oyIGKD2Gxtjg8BHi4cYJkmKZpjAThTjiIp3Lh8aJsmqb2k4rC3I4xynOcSRXFKs4fPaSGFlBeKfDycEHnaPL8pBABE2w5k44n5L+Qx-saMGCX6cKIgOOZDr+hyJKMVATOOWrUrMknVjJyyrPxCgeqhYbcEAA)

Comment: The compiler can't do higher-order analysis of `Element<T>` when `T` is generic (or depends on a generic).  *You* know that `Element<Product["trucks"]>` will be equivalent to `Product["trucks"][number]` and thus some subtype of `Truck`, but the compiler doesn't because it doesn't think "oh, `Element<T>` will turn `T` into its element type if `T` is an array"; it just says "I don't know what `T` is yet so I can't evaluate this".  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I'll stick to `unknown` cast then.

Comment: I'll write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript isn't able to relate `Builder<Element<Product["trucks"]>>` to `TruckBuilder` because `Product` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) type parameter and `Element` is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  So `Element<Product["trucks"]>` is a so-called *generic conditional type*, and TypeScript is notoriously unable to do much analysis on such types.

Before a generic type parameter is specified with a type argument, it can be any subtype of its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), and conditional types can do almost arbitrarily complex things.  Instead of trying to analyze such types in the hopes that it can make some higher order statement about the full set of possibilities, the compiler tends to just *defer* evaluation.   So in `Element<Product["trucks"]>` the compiler doesn't know what `Product` will be, and `Element` is a conditional type, so it essentially gives up on evaluating `Element<Product["trucks"]>`.  It is easy for a human being (especially the one who wrote the code) to look at `Element<Product["trucks"]>` and say "`Product["trucks"]` will be some subtype of `Truck[]` and thus `Element<Product["trucks"]>` will be some subtype of `Truck` because, when given an array type, `Element` returns its element type."  But the compiler doesn't have such abilities.

---

So, since you're doing a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) anyway, you don't need to actually convince the compiler that the types are fully assignable, just that they are "related" to each other.  Type assertions are intended to let you do things the compiler can't verify as safe, but if the types involved aren't seen as "related" then the compiler will warn you anyway.  This can always be worked around by asserting to an intermediate type which is related to both the original expression and the final type.  So if `x as T` doesn't work, you can write `x as U as T` where `U` is related to `T` and `typeof X`.

So, what type is related both to `TruckBuilder` and to `Builder<Element<Product["trucks"]>>`?  You could use [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) which, as the universal supertype, is related to everything.  But this wouldn't catch even egregious mistakes like `return TruckBuilder as unknown as Builder<Element<Product["trucks"]>>`... oops, I returned the constructor instead of an instance.  There's nothing necessarily *wrong* with writing `as unknown as`, but it's a bit more powerful than you need.

You might want to find an intermediate type which is "closer" to the actual types.  For example: `Builder<Truck>`.  The compiler sees that `TruckBuilder` is related to `Builder<Truck>`, because it's a subtype of `Builder<Truck>`. And, interestingly, it is also happy enough to see `Builder<Truck>` as related to `Builder<Element<Product["trucks"]>>`, probably because they are both written in terms of `Builder`.  That means, it doesn't worry about the generic conditional type `Element<Product["trucks"]>>` and just sees two `Builder<⋯>` as related.

So that gives us

```
return this.setChild("trucks", () => {
  return new TruckBuilder() as
    Builder<Truck> as Builder<Element<Product["trucks"]>>;
});
```

which compiles without error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgIQFcEAbAEzQB4AFKCMw7GAPjgG8BYAKDjgCNi5ABQBKAFxxa9RjADc3AL7duoSLDgwAnmDwBREsAC2wFJQAqrALxwzcUKiRkAznACCUKJk2Vk6NHABNVgB+QLgJM3kuVWh4LR0CQQooAEkkBBgaOgYmABo4AGlgTTsQB2c4AGtiiHRJbJkrOCFuXjAGpgkpHJhc7hE4S1YiUmTKfSMTTO6ZAG0izQBdZmYo7kw+JxhPJjhsEkwnF2pMKCmR8ioZ3fsTCog+ACtgJlZOHjgzzDIIJBISgDE2AAFqMzkgALKYMCDOBIYAAdzgULAlFavCqNTq1166N4F2SaQyWWkeUxmlq9VJLFmi3RzFEaw+7QgqCYwDIcCcwBgAGFQeRKAtSuUXNUKdiOiwWh9eOKJAs+rK9nwJAS0ETplL8gtmEreAN3hiNKCnAA6IECsjglFm7kwITi-KzbB8RYiJnGs4wQhQJAmhBOKK8JRcUPcZCoDA4PC8iCGMCYJCaVxHHkuI0aKCMSpOCLZ7CVWlRcNcfaHFxmAuVdjo7AQEjQACEEi2UGQAHMS8oywcjjZq+qoIgEwZjCgXEPzNW3uiAPRztzJuDfMgZBC-TAkPb0PC-AMucv9wN7TCEJydk14QNOQh4PjARsIs3opzx4AQnnA+iiWvKhd2AmWjoqWvACKMv6Zrw3q+v68JIlWOaMiBig9hsbY4PAR4uHGCZJimaYwE4U44iKdw4fGibJqm9pOKwtyOMcpznEkVxSrOHz2ohhaQXinw8rBB52jy-IQQARNsOZOGJ+S-kMf7GtBAl+nCiIDjmQ6-ocfHGlO3GVKwhyJKMVATOOWrUrMEnVtJyyrHxCgeihYbcEAA)

Comment: What a superb answer. Thanks so much for explaining this in so much detail. I'll most certainly utilize this knowledge going forward.